# Presence of `var` within an `if` influences whether the if is evaluated?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scope, global

This is some specific subtlety to do with Javascript scoping and global vs local variables that I don't quite understand - and can result in the surprising situation of the code within an `if` condition influencing whether that `if` condition is evaluated: code being influenced by code that hasn't 'happened' yet.

I've whittled it down to this [**JSBIN DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/neyeqica/1/edit) comparing two near-identical chunks of code.

---

In the first, everything happens as expected. We define a global variable, then within a scope, we check if it's defined, see that it is, and carry on:

```
someVar = function(){}; // or, window.someVar =...

(function(){

console.log("before", someVar, typeof someVar);
if(typeof someVar == 'undefined'){
  someVar = true;
}
console.log("after", someVar, typeof someVar);

})();
```

The console shows the variable is a function and the if is skipped, as expected.

**However**, if we change the line within the `if` to use `var`, it *changes the status of the variable **before** that change in the code is reached*.

In this variant, where nothing has changed except the addition of `var` to the line within the `if`, the variable switches to `undefined` two lines previously, and the `if` is now evaluated:

```
someVar = function(){}; // or, window.someVar =...

(function(){

console.log("before", someVar, typeof someVar);
if(typeof someVar == 'undefined'){
  var someVar = true; // <<<<< the only change is adding var here
}
console.log("after", someVar, typeof someVar);

})();
```

The console shows the variable to now be `undefined` before the `if`, and switched by the `if` which is now evaluated.

**Edit:** Turns out the same thing happens even if the `var` statement **can never happen**:

```
neverVar = function(){}; // or, window.neverVar ...

(function(){

console.log("never-before", neverVar, typeof neverVar);
if(false){ // never do this
  var neverVar = "changed";
}
console.log("never-after", neverVar, typeof neverVar);

})();
```

I didn't think it was possible for JS code to influence the execution of code before it's been reached - but clearly the presence of `var` later on in the code is somehow stopping the whole scope from looking globally.

Judging by jsbin's warnings, whether or not it is considered out of scope depends on whether there is a `var` statement in the scope, even if that `var` statement hasn't been evaluated or would not be expected to be evaluated.

Can someone explain this?

---

(side question, out of curiosity, are there any other examples of Javascript execution being influenced by the mere presence of unevaluated code?)

Comment: In addition to the answer given, don't forget that Javascript default scope is not block scope, it's function scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), where variable and function declarations are processed before the rest of the code is actually executed.

Whenever a `var` is encountered in a non-global scope, a new variable is declared and initialized at `undefined` in that scope. Since `if` does not introduce a new (block) scope, `var` inside `if` shadows the `var` from the parent scope.

---

Bonus: regarding your side question whether there are any other examples of JavaScript execution being influenced by unreachable code: Yes, but only in terms of performance. Modern JavaScript interpreters are quite sophisticated and try to optimize the interpreted code as much as possible. There are [some constructs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#user-content-2-unsupported-syntax) that result in a performance hit, even if it is within an unreachable code block. For example:

```
for (var i=0; i<100000000; ++i) ; // Busy loop
if (false) {
   eval(); // BOOM - Killed optimizations.
}
```

Check out the benchmark: The snippet containing `eval` runs significantly  slower than the one without: http://jsperf.com/eval-hurts-performance.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - I've been baffled for nearly 1 1/2 hours and you answered in 90 seconds! Quick query: can you clarify "encountered" in this context? By my niave understanding, the code in the `if` would not be evaluated - but presumably there's some kind of scanning of the whole scope that happens before the code is actually evaluated?

Comment: @user568458 "encountered" as in "present in the function". Read the article I linked for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: @user568458 I just noticed your side question and appended a small remark at the end of my answer, FYI ;)

Comment: :D Thanks! This line in that article really helps: **"Function declarations and variable declarations are always moved (“hoisted”) invisibly to the top of their containing scope by the JavaScript interpreter"**. Presumably meaning that `function(){ ...some code... var someVar = 10; }` is treated as identical to `function(){ var someVar; ...some code... someVar = 10; }`